# Replace the string characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

If I have string like

```
select field1 + N' ' + field2 + N' ' + field3 from table1
```

how to make so that I could change or replace the characters starting from third place to fifth?

I mean if select statement above returns a string `ABCD EFGH IJKL`, then I want to replace `CD(space)` with `*`

Thanks.

Comment: try using `stuff function`

Comment: You can use either Stuff or replace function.

Comment: replace the space including CD or just the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the stuff function:

```
SELECT STUFF('ABCD EFGH IJKL', 3, 3, '*');

select STUFF(field1 + N' ' + field2 + N' ' + field3, 3, 3, '*') from table1
```

Syntax:

```
STUFF ( character_expression , start , length , replaceWith_expression )
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel STUFF function is the best way to go about it.

Below is a small example on how i would approach the same

```
CREATE TABLE TESTDATA
(
  DATA NVARCHAR(MAX),
  DATA1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
  DATA2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

 INSERT INTO TESTDATA VALUES('ABCD','HGHG','HGFD')
 INSERT INTO TESTDATA VALUES('HHGG','ADFS', 'ERET')
 INSERT INTO TESTDATA VALUES('JKJK','GGHG', 'TRED')

 DECLARE @DATA TABLE(DATA VARCHAR(100))
 INSERT INTO @DATA select STUFF(DATA + N' ',3,3,'*')  + DATA1 + N' ' + DATA2 from TESTDATA
 SELECT * FROM @DATA
```

**The Result for the same would be**,

```
AB*HGHG HGFD
HH*ADFS ERET
JK*GGHG TRED
```

I hope the above was useful

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
  select replace(field1 + N' ' + field2 + N' ' + field3, 'CD ', '*') from
 table1
```

Comment: Hi,
This only works if we know exactly what string we have, but if don't then?